# How to specify setRejectedExecutionHandler, prestartAllCoreThreads, allowCoreThreadTimeOut of ThreadingService in Esper V8.5

Tags: java, complex-event-processing, esper

We used to set different Thread Pool parameters in Esper V5.2 as below -

```
EPServiceProvider epServiceProvider = EPServiceProviderManager.getDefaultProvider(configuration);
//In configuration we have some custom function.
EPServiceProviderSPI serviceProviderSPI = (EPServiceProviderSPI) epServiceProvider;
ThreadPoolExecutor inboundThreadPool = serviceProviderSPI.getThreadingService().getInboundThreadPool();

inboundThreadPool.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
inboundThreadPool.setCorePoolSize(coreSize);
inboundThreadPool.setMaximumPoolSize(maxSize);
inboundThreadPool.prestartAllCoreThreads();
inboundThreadPool.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(false);

EPRuntime runtime = epServiceProvider.getEPRuntime();
```

Now that in esper V8.5 overall logic is changed, how do we specify the above similar paramters?

In Esper V8.5 we have written as below way -

```
EPRuntime epRuntime = EPRuntimeProvider.getDefaultRuntime(configuration);
//In configuration we have some custom function.
```

I see that there is a class called EPRuntimeSPI which extends EPRuntime and which has ThreadingService methods. Do we need to use this class to set those thread pool parameters? If yes then how?

We need to set this parameter otherwise when the executor services is shutdown then all the remaining tasks(tasks is nothing but logic of loading each esper statement) are getting rejected.

Answer (score 0):

EPRuntimeSPI replaced EPServiceProviderSPI and it should thus be the same.